# Kestrel isn't "using" pfx file for https

Tags: c#

My local development is wanting to install a localhost ssl certificate even though I have specified a pfx I want it to use.

core API .NET 5.0

My understanding was that kestrel was used by default so this is what I have done.

In my hosts file I setup a FQDN.

```
127.0.0.1   myapi.mysite.com
```

In my program.cs I added ConfigureKestrel

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44394, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        var serverCertificate = LoadCertificate();
                        listenOptions.UseHttps(serverCertificate); // <- Configures SSL
                    });
                });
            });


    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var embeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly, "My.API");
        var certificateFileInfo = embeddedFileProvider.GetFileInfo("wildcard_mydomain_com.pfx");
        using (var certificateStream = certificateFileInfo.CreateReadStream())
        {
            byte[] certificatePayload;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                certificateStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                certificatePayload = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            return new X509Certificate2(certificatePayload, "password");
        }
    }
```

I do not get any errors but I don't get the custom domain certificate presented to the browser either. The browser tell me I am unsecure and wants me to accept the localhost cert....which I don't want to accept. I want my custom domain cert to be used.

Am I not understanding how the certs work in a browser?

Doesn't the web server present the cert to the browser and the browser checks to see if it is issued by a legit CA?

Am I loading my custom cert but not "attaching" it to the development server to use?

Comment: The "visual-studio" tag is not appriprate here as your question has no relation to the development environment itself.

Comment: Is this an officially issued certificate matching your web domain?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes...it's an officially issued wilcard for my domain.